# summernote calls upload image on file select instead of insert image

Tags: summernote

I added summernote in my rails project and implemented code to save image in  server using

```
$(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".summernote_custom").summernote({
           height: 200,
           styleTags: ['p', 'h1', 'h2'],
           toolbar: [
                 ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                 ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph','style']],
                 ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                 ['fontsize',['fontsize']],
                 ['insert', ['picture','link']]
           ],
           dialogsInBody: true,
            callbacks: {
               onImageUpload: function(files) {
                 uploadImage(files[0],$(this));
               }
             }
         });
    });

    function uploadImage(image,editor) {
      var data = new FormData();
      data.append("image",image);
      data.append("name", "resource");
      $.ajax ({
        data: data,
        type: "POST",
        url: "#{ajax_upload_doctor_attachments_path}",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data) {
          editor.summernote("insertImage", "#{HOST}" + data.url, function ($image) {
            $image.css('width', '100%');
            $image.attr('data-filename', 'retriever');
          });

        },
        error: function(data) {
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
    }
```

Everything working fine only issue is that it insert image on file select and closes popup instead of waiting for click of "insert image" button.

How can I change this behaviour

Comment: I have the same issue, did you ever resolve it?

Comment: sorry, never found any solution.